# CORS Error when changing headers with Axios

Tags: javascript, api, http, axios, cors

I'm trying to send a post request with Axios from my frontend to Zoho API. When I send the post request without any new headers ex. `let data = await axios.post(dataUrl);`, I get a 401 response from the api I'm calling because I am not supplying the authorization token. When I try to add the authorization ex.

```
let data = await axios.post(
          dataUrl,
          {},
          {
            ["Authorization"]: `Zoho-oauthtoken ${accessToken}}`,
          }
        );
```

I get a CORS error on the request, so I'm unable to get any response from the server.[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dGdg.png).

I've tried adding `access-control-allow-headers: "*",` which didn't make a difference. Even when I remove the authorization header  and send

```
let data = await axios.post(dataUrl,{},{});
```

I get the same cors issue.

Comment: Wait what is Zoho API, is that your backend, can you modify its code? If you don't have access to modify it to add your own frontend Link to the allowed origins list for receiving HTTP requests then there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: It is not my api so I can’t modify the code. However, I can make a request to to the api without modifying headers (just get 401 back) so I don’t believe it’s an issue with the api itself @Aleksandar

Comment: Axios silently adds a `Content-Type` header when the second argument to post is an object. You'd need to configure CORS on the server side to allow both `Content-Type` and `Authorization` as request headers. But if you're consuming a third-party API, you can't change their CORS configuration; you'll have to consume that API from your backend rather than from your frontend.